# BlackBerry back to screen detection

Tags: blackberry, screen

HI, I try to detect reterning to screen after closing another screen,
 should work when returning from my application screens, but also returning from device camera 
 after shooting video. In overriden method onExposed() I'm able to detect this situation,
 but it's called too many times, and also called when dialog was shown (alert).
 Is there better way to detect return to screen?

```
protected void onExposed() {
    // return to screen detected
    MainApp.addLog("onExposed");
}
```

Comment: hay how u used that Application.activate method in class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> returning from device camera after
>   shooting video

Check the [Application.activate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#activate%28%29)

> The system invokes this method when it
>   brings this application to the
>   foreground. By default, this method
>   does nothing. Override this method to
>   perform additional processing when
>   being brought to the foreground.

Comment: thanks this works, but I also need returning to screen inside application

Comment: as to 'returning to screen' I just don't know what to suggest. this sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: how to use Application.activate() method in class file ? pls provide any sample code if u have

Answer (score 1):

If you override the [Screen.onUiEngineAttached(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onUiEngineAttached%28boolean%29) method, you can be notified when the screen is attached or detached from the UI --- basically when it's pushed or popped from the screen stack.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar thing and found it's very confusing because onExposed() can be called multiple times in uncertain timing.
To detect returning from screen B in screen A (main screen), I used screen B's onUiEngineAttached(false) which is called when it is popped.
To use callback:

```
public interface Ievent {
    public void backFromScreenBEvent();
}
```

Screen A:

```
public class ScreenA extends MainScreen implements Ievent
{
    private ScreenB screenB;

    // constructor
    public ScreenA()
    {
        screenB = new ScreenB(this); // pass over Ievent
        // ....
    }

    public void backFromScreenBEvent()
    {
        // screen B is returning, do something
    }
```

Screen B:

```
public final class ScreenB extends MainScreen
{
    private Ievent event;

    // constructor  
    public ScreenB(final Ievent event)
    {
        this.event = event;
        // ...
    }

    protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
        super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
        if (!attached) {
            event.backFromScreenBEvent(); // notify event
        }
    }
```